# Can't use ODataQueryOptions with a (regular - not webapi) Controller derived class?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

```
public class XYZController : Controller
    {            

        public ActionResult Index(ODataQueryOptions<Security> options = null)
        {
            var xyzs= GetXYZs().AsQueryable();
            var results = options == null ? xyzs: options.ApplyTo(xyzs);
            return View(xyzs);
        }
     }
```

This results in "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" error.

I essentially want to pass odata compliant parameters in to a regular controller.

Can this not be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I temporarily (until regular controllers can use ODataQueryOptions) solved this through the use of Linq2Rest (NuGet: install-package Linq2Rest)

This quite powerful library allowed me to accomplish what I am looking for with one line of code:

```
using Linq2Rest;

 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var filteredSource = GetXYZs().AsQueryable().Filter(Request.Params);

            return View(filteredSource);
        }
```

Now you can hit this Controller's Index Action like this:
[xyz.com?$filter=something eq 'foo' and another gt 3&$orderby another](http://xyz.com?%24filter=something%20eq%20%27foo%27%20and%20another%20gt%203&%24orderby%20another)

Answer (score 0):

`ODataQueryOptions<T>` is only supported with web API now. That said, this is an interesting scenario. I have opened this [issue](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1123) on codeplex to track it.

Comment: Thanks - I wonder if there is a way to manually instantiate the ODataQueryOptions from the request context or pass in filter, sort, group, count, etc string patameters which then somehow are used to manually initialize an ODataQueryOptions context...